# trouble accessing files on mounted google drive in colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have my google drive mounted in colab using:

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

Under My Drive, I have a folder called Data whose content I wish to access. The problem is, whenever I try to do something with this folder, either by just checking whether it is there:

`!ls /content/gdrive/My\ Drive/`

or trying to read a csv in that folder:

```py
datapath = '/content/gdrive/My Drive/Data/'
scores = pd.read_csv(datapath+'Scores.csv')
```

It creates an empty folder with the same name (Data) under My Drive, and returns an error saying no file was found in Data. When I use `!ls`, it shows a folder named Data and a file named 'Data (1)' under My Drive.

Answer (score -1):

from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/content/gdrive/My Drive/Data/Scores.csv')
df.head()

Comment: Just to clarify, I did import pandas as pd, the error is not missing pd module. It is the creation of empty folders with the same name of the folder I'm trying to access under My Drive.